# О каком фреймворке идет речь?

Tags: php

Быстрый

Простой

Развивающийся или уже доделанный

Подходит для высоко нагруженных проектов

Есть аналог модреврайта внутри фреймворка

Нет избыточного извращенства с нэймспейсами, наследовнием и классами.

Подходит для создания веб приложений на продажу

Comment: Это загадка или вопрос?

Answer (score 2):

Yii

Comment: Теперь уже надо уточнять, версия 1.* :)

Comment: ну я считаю, что нужно стремиться всегда к последний версиям. 


Version 1.1.14
http://static.yiiframework.com/files/CHANGELOG-1.1.14.txt

не плохо пофиксили

Comment: Последней у Yii сейчас есть 2.0 (пока что Public Preview) http://www.yiiframework.com/news/71/yii-2-public-preview-available/.

Там она не попадет в пункты с отсутствием неймспейсов и 100% готовностью

Answer (score 2):

Phalcon

Answer (score 0):

Все зависит от Ваших навыков. Я учился на [зенде](http://framework.zend.com/). После него все фраемворки понятны). 
Если важна скорость разработки и красота кода не критична берите Yii. Там и кодгенератор и комьюнити большое. Снизьте свой круг к этим двум, и уже между ними выбирайтею. Как вариант ещё [symfony](http://symfony.com/). Но мне он как-то не понравился с первых шагов.